# why this function is not returning the data. it showing only undefine while print it out

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

**I just tried to make one function that will take CSV files and return JSON data. when I console out the data it will work fine but when I tried to return the same data it will return undefined**.

```
var fs = require('fs');

//sorting the json...
function compareStrings(a, b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}

//reding csv and converting it into json..........
var csv_to_json = ()=>{
    fs.readFile('./Data/book.csv',(err,data)=>{
        let jsonData = [];
        var content = data.toString().split('\n').join().split('\r');
        var key = content[0].split(';');
        content.shift();

        content.forEach((item)=>{
            var temp = item.replace(",").split(';');
            var data = {}
            for(var i=0;i<key.length;i++){
                data[key[i]] = temp[i]
            }

            jsonData.push(data);
        })

        jsonData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return compareStrings(a.title, b.title);
        })

    // console.log is working fine but when I tried to return the same data it won't work properly

        // console.log(jsonData);
        return jsonData;
    })
}

console.log(csv_to_json())
```

Comment: `csv_to_json` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: i want to return the data that the function (csv_to_json) is consolling out so that further I can store it in any variable,  example:-   **var my_data = csv_to_json()**

Answer (score 0):

Because you use a callback function and when use callback function you code execute asynchronously

I suggest you read [this document](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/#:%7E:text=loads%20the%20data.-,Node.,be%20run%20in%20the%20meantime.)

You have to change code like that:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

//sorting the json...
function compareStrings(a, b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}

//reding csv and converting it into json..........
var csv_to_json = (callback)=>{
    fs.readFile('./Data/book.csv',(err,data)=>{
        let jsonData = [];
        var content = data.toString().split('\n').join().split('\r');
        var key = content[0].split(';');
        content.shift();

        content.forEach((item)=>{
            var temp = item.replace(",").split(';');
            var data = {}
            for(var i=0;i<key.length;i++){
                data[key[i]] = temp[i]
            }

            jsonData.push(data);
        })

        jsonData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return compareStrings(a.title, b.title);
        })

    // console.log is working fine but when I tried to return the same data it won't work properly

        // console.log(jsonData);
        callback(null, jsonData);
    })
}

csv_to_json((error, data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: well, it's again consoling out the data, but I want to store the data in a variable when we assign it to. example:-  **var my_data = csv_to_json()**     so for that the function should return the data but it won't

Comment: First better read how nodejs callback work, you can't store variable like `var my_data = csv_to_json()`  if your function was callback, I suggest you to use async/await it is easy to store variable `var my_data = await csv_to_json()`